# WeasyPrint unable to load images/css: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: weasyprint

I'm using WeasyPrint 52.3 (latest version available at time of writing) along with Django 2.2 LTS on Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 development machine; all is working fine.

However when I try to render a PDF on my Linux machine (same WeasyPrint/Django/Python versions), all items I try to load from an URI are not shown, including images and CSS. When not using WeasyPrint, images/CSS are properly loaded. My images/CSS are available at `https://myhost.tld/some.css` and `myhost` has its certs signed.

When using inline CSS, the CSS is rendered fine.

I've tried to enable WeasyPrint logging through:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('weasyprint')
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/tmp/weasyprint.log'))
```

and I see following output:

```
Failed to load stylesheet at https://myhost.tld/assets/css/pdf.css : URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

How can this be? My DNS system is properly set up for myhost.tld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure `myhost.tld` is part of the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myhost
127.0.2.1 myhost.tld
```

Restart the right services and the files will load.